# Why isn’t electric potential energy involved in the calculation of pair production?

Tags: potential-energy, quantum-electrodynamics, pair-production

When I learned about energy conservation in pair production, we only considered the energy of matter and light. Why isn’t the electric potential involved? Also why isn’t the gravitational potential energy involved?

Answer (score 0):

The effect of electric and gravitational potential energies is not usually considered because they are so small, of order $10^{-5}$ in the electric case and many, many, many orders of magnitude smaller for gravity.

The effect of **electromagnetic** interactions between the pair-produced electron and positron can be estimated in a couple of ways, either by considering the possible [quantum electrodynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) (QED) processes  or by simply estimating the effect of the electric potential energy on the mass of the system.

As shown in the QED diagram on the left, the lowest order process for [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) is proportional to $\alpha^3$, where $\alpha\approx 1/137$ is the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant).

[image: Feynman diagrams for lowest order pair production and lowest order diagram with a virtual photon between the electron and positron]

The lowest order contribution from electromagnetic interactions between the electron and positron is shown on the right, and from counting the points where photons couple to charged particles we see that this will be proportional to $\alpha^5$, so its effect on the pair production probability will be about $\alpha^2\sim 5\times 10^{-5}$.

This can also be seen by considering that the electromagnetic interaction between the electron and positron lowers the threshold energy for electron-positron production by about 6.8 eV, i.e. the binding ($\alpha^2 m_e /4$) energy of the lowest [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#Energy_levels) state.
The high energy [pair production cross section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section)   is
$$\sigma \sim \frac{4\alpha^3}{m_{e^+e^-}^2} Z^2$$

The threshold mass of the electron-positron system is normally considered to be $m_{e^+e^-}=2m_e$, but the binding energy reduces this by $\alpha^2 m_e /4$, so the cross-section could increase by a factor of
$$\frac{1}{(1-\alpha^2/8)^2}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha^2/4+\alpha^4/64)} \sim 1+\alpha^2/4$$
So again we see the effect of electromagnetic interactions between the positron and electron is of order $\alpha^2$.

The **gravitational** force between an electron and positron is completely negligible since it is weaker than the coulomb force between them by a factor of
$$\left({G\frac{m_e^2}{r^2}}\middle/\frac{q_e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\right)=\frac{4\pi \epsilon_0 Gm_e^2}{q_e^2}\sim 10^{-42}$$
Because there is no accepted quantum theory of gravity, I won't try to estimate the precise effect on pair production, but it is very, very, very, very small.